# What's the best way to track versions on a specific column of a table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a webapp that for these purposes can be considered a collaborative blog or wiki. People view a set of documents and edit then republish them, and we need to keep track of a revision history on published versions of a particular document. Scale would be tens-of-thousands of documents, each with ten revisions (order of magnitude + or - 1) and order of magnitude hundreds of users, with tens having interest in revision histories.

The document itself is simple enough (just a text column with some ownership/ACL and tag attributes), and I'm thinking of several ways to handle the revision system. Approach A would be to have another column on the doc table that tracks version number. So document id 1 could have version 1, 2, 3 etc. In that case, the table would need an index on (id, version) rather than just id.

QUESTION: Is this a bad idea? Not even sure if it's feasible in activerecord for postgres to have a doc without a single column primary key. I could also have a doc_id column and index on (doc_id, version_id). This is compelling enough, since that way calls to my REST endpoint for /doc/:id would return the head, and /doc/:id?ver=N would return version N. Maps nicely into what I want to do.

The other option I'm considering would be a separate history table, so the document table contains the last version, and I throw everything else into another table for history. That doesn't seem to be all that useful at first, but the history-table approach affords things like blame (who made this change) and other data to be saved about the history. I've looked at the paper_trail gem, which does a lot of this, but paper_trail is written for a much more generic use-case, and I just need to track changes on one text column.

So, suggestions? My database-organization skills are slowly coming up to speed, and I feel like this is a place where I can make a pretty critical mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using something like **paper trail** (https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) I've used it before for a similar set of tasks and I like it for versioning.

Comment: I have, it seems useful but perhaps overkill for this particular scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the `(id, version)` approach is that it's clumsy and inefficient to get the latest one, and that's what you'll want to do most of the time.

I strongly suggest storing old versions out-of-line in a side table. Don't try to number versions sequentially, e.g. 1, 2, 3, 4; store them by *date*. If you want a version number series when displaying it, use the `row_number()` window function, eg:

```
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY version_created_time),
       version_text
FROM versions;
```

Also, you're using ActiveRecord, which is an awful opinionated ORM that refuses to properly support all sorts of useful basic relational database features like natural composite keys. Trying to make it do so is likely to be a world of pain.